# AHK Hotstring for Multi-language Input

Tags: automation, autohotkey, ahk2

I am bilingual (English and Persian), and I regularly switch between keyboard input languages by pressing Alt + Shift. Since it's not an easy type, I am trying to create a hotstring in Auto Hot Key (AHK) to send Alt + Shift by pressing `jf`:

```
:*?:jf::
    SendInput, {AltDown}{Shift}{AltUp}
Return
```

While this works perfect, I need to press the same keys in Persian language to switch back to English, so I updated the code to:

```
:*?:jf::
:*?:تب::
    SendInput, {AltDown}{Shift}{AltUp}
Return
```

Now, the second line doesn't work, and by putting a breakpoint on the SendInput line, pressing those keys in Persian, does not even trigger the hotstring. Any solution? Thanks!

Here are the things I've tried to fix and failed:

- Using Send and SendInput methods
- swapping the order of `jf` and `تب` lines
- Compiling the code to see if the .exe works

Comment: Persian (isn't the language actually called _Farsi_ ?), being written with a variation of the Arabic alphabet, has contextually-sensitive letter forms. Try ensuring that your AHK script shows the two isolate forms, not the "correct" connected style.

Comment: Did you  [save the script as UTF-8 with BOM](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/FAQ.htm#nonascii)?

Comment: @Relax saving as UTF-8 with BOM actually worked, THANKS!

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Farsi to Persian is like Deutsch to German! (  ͡~ ͜つ ͡ᵔ )